# WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() in owin middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, owin

We're using following OWIN middleware in our web app to impersonate user based on incoming request.

```cs
public class SomeMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public SomeMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var identity = context.Authentication.User?.Identity;
        
        if(identity is WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity)
        {
            using var ctx = windowsIdentity.Impersonate();
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The other middleware in pipeline logs stuff with log4net. The appender layout template has user identity.

Sometimes the web app blows up with following error.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, UInt32& ReturnLength)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()
   at log4net.Core.LoggingEvent.get_Identity()
   at log4net.Layout.Pattern.IdentityPatternConverter.Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Layout.Pattern.PatternLayoutConverter.Convert(TextWriter writer, Object state)
   at log4net.Util.PatternConverter.Format(TextWriter writer, Object state)
   at log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.Format(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.RenderLoggingEvent(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.TextWriterAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.FileAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
...
Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.CreateFromToken(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity..ctor(IntPtr userToken, String authType, Int32 isAuthenticated)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity..ctor(SafeAccessTokenHandle safeTokenHandle)
   at System.Security.SecurityContext.CaptureCore(Reader currThreadEC, StackCrawlMark&amp;amp; stackMark)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Capture(StackCrawlMark&amp;amp; stackMark, CaptureOptions options)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.FastCapture()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.GetCompletionAction(Task taskForTracing, MoveNextRunner&amp;amp; runnerToInitialize)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted[TAwaiter,TStateMachine](TAwaiter&amp;amp; awaiter, TStateMachine&amp;amp; stateMachine)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c.&amp;lt;ThrowAsync&amp;gt;b__6_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ArgumentException: Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated.
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.CreateFromToken(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity..ctor(IntPtr userToken, String authType, Int32 isAuthenticated)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity..ctor(SafeAccessTokenHandle safeTokenHandle)
   at System.Security.SecurityContext.CaptureCore(Reader currThreadEC, StackCrawlMark&amp;amp; stackMark)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Capture(StackCrawlMark&amp;amp; stackMark, CaptureOptions options)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.FastCapture()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.GetCompletionAction(Task taskForTracing, MoveNextRunner&amp;amp; runnerToInitialize)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted[TAwaiter,TStateMachine](TAwaiter&amp;amp; awaiter, TStateMachine&amp;amp; stateMachine)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c.&amp;lt;ThrowAsync&amp;gt;b__6_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

How likely is the middleware at fault here? Am I looking at the wrong place?